How to Preserve Formatting in Long Text Field Input for Screen Flows
I have a screen flow that takes in input through a long text field and then inputs it into a text template used for an email. The formatting from the long text field is not preserved for some reason wen inputted into the text template for the email. When the email is received, all line breaks are removed. Is there any way to preserve line breaks, bullet points, etc.?
